# Windows service that won't run multiple services

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have created a Windows Service in Visual Studio 2012 that should run 2 services when executed.

```
static void Main()
    {
        // creates an array to hold all services that will run in this application
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        {
            // services added here
            new Service1(),
            new Service2()
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
```

I have already read various possible answers in various forums, etc. but I have not found a working solution for me.

I have added a Service Installer for each service and I also have one project installer.

When I install the service through the Developer Command Prompt I can see the Windows Service in the Computer Manager but I can also see Service1 and Service2.

When I run the Windows Service, it will only run Service1 and not Service2.  However, both Service1 and Service2 can be started individually.

Anyone any suggestions?  Been stuck on this for some time now!

**EDIT**

In the Service1 and Service2 OnStart() I have the following code:

```
CheckService();

        try
        {
            motorTimer = new Timer();
            // timer sets intervals for when quotes are checked after start up
            motorTimer .Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(QuoteTimerElapsed);
            motorTimer .Interval = Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ServiceCheckInterval"]);
            motorTimer .Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MotorServiceCheckLogDetail(ex.ToString());
            OnStop();
        }
```

Comment: I had a similar problem once and then decided to split it up into multiple services instead of putting all those "subservices" into one big.

Comment: What is in your OnStart? method of Service 2

Comment: Actually, it may be more interesting what is in your OnStart() method in Service1? If it does not return promptly I think the service manager gives up on starting the following services.

Comment: @YaugenVlasau I have code in the OnStart() that should run when this service starts.  Should I be adding something to link it to Service1?

Comment: Could you also set your Autolog property to true and see what it writes in the event log?

Comment: @RenniePet again I just have a call to another method in the Service1 OnStart().  I also have a timer in both OnStart() for Service1 and Service2

Comment: I would recomend add some logging in OnStart method of two service and check if everething goes smoothly

Comment: A common mistake for beginners with Windows services is to not realize the the work of the service must NOT be done in the OnStart() method - or any methods it calls. Instead, OnStart() should just start a thread to do the work and then return as quick as it can.

Comment: @YaugenVlasau I have added some extra logging so I will check it out and see if I can get any more info. Thanks

Comment: Is that a Thread.Timer or a WinForms Timer?

Comment: @RenniePet are you saying that OnStart() should have no code in it and it should also not call any other methods in that particular service class?  Have you an example of what you mean?  Thanks for the response

Comment: @RenniePet it is a System.Timers Timer

Comment: Yes, that was a dumb question. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx is the official documentation. Does OnStart() just call CheckService() and then return, or does it do more?  EDIT: If what you've shown above is all you have in OnStart() then it does look OK. Don't know what the problem is.

Comment: @RenniePet what was a dumb question??? The OnStart() calls the CheckService() and has the Timer code as above.  It doesn't do any more.  I appreciate all help, I am still relatively new to programming and working with Windows Services

Comment: Me asking which kind of Timer it was, that was a dumb question. Sorry, I can't see what your problem can be - it's not as simple as I was assuming.

Comment: @RenniePet yeah it's been annoying me for quite some time now. I'll keep working away and post my solution if I find it.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: One last stab in the dark: What exactly does that CheckService() method do? It's not something that can wait for any period of time, is it?

Comment: @RenniePet step by step - the CheckService() will start a Stopwatch, call a method from a WebService, stop the Stopwatch and then depending on the outcome of some conditional statements it will write to a file and/or send an email.

Comment: Well, if that processing can take a second or more that may be enough to prevent things from being considered OK. Try doing what Yaugen Vlasau is suggesting, and move everything out of OnStart() except for starting a new thread, and do all your work there.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, you say "both Service1 and Service2 can be started individually" so it sounds as if it is all working properly.   Are you expecting that Service2 will start whenever you start Service1?  That isn't supposed to happen, the two services should start and stop independently of one another, they simply share a process for efficiency.

Comment: Are you talking about running the service executable directly, for debugging purposes?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: My understanding of the ServiceBase.Run() method when used with an array of ServiceBase objects is that it's supposed to start all of them. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6esb073b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx (But I must admit I've never used that technique myself.)

Comment: @RenniePet: that documentation is misleading.  What it should have said is that the SCM will issue start commands *for the service(s) that it has been asked to start*, which may or may not include all of the services the process has registered.  (During system startup that will include all services that are configured to start automatically, otherwise it will usually only be a single service at a time.)  Granted, I haven't used that class either, but I know how services are supposed to work, and that isn't it. :-)

Comment: (If you do want all of the functionality in the executable to always run at the same time, why split it into separate services in the first place?  The whole point of having multiple services is so you can start and stop them independently.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: OK, thanks for responding. So what you're saying is that what the OP is experiencing is not a bug, it's a feature. In that case, an alternative way to attack it, instead of merging his functionality into one service, would be to have the first service start the second one, as well as doing what it's supposed to do. Or else (and here I do have some experience) have one super-service program that starts and stops other services.

Comment: @RenniePet: presumably the OP would also want to stop service B when service A is stopped - that might be a bit tricky, depending on how the .NET class is implemented, but doable; and also start service A when service B is started and stop service A when service B is stopped.  It can all be done, no doubt, but it would be *much* easier to implement as a single service, and I don't see any advantage to the more complicated approach.

Comment: @HarryJohnston thanks for your input and help on this problem.  I was originally set this job in work and asked to split to serperate services but start as one service.  I will have to reassess the situation and either combine or keep seperate.  I appreciate all your help, thanks!  If you want to combine what you've said I can mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer to my problem I took the following approach.  It might not be perfect and I slightly changed my approach but it was a way I was able to get my Service to work how I wanted.

Instead of creating 1 service with multiple 'services' being run within it, I created one service that instantiated various classes.  I was able to include the functionality required in these classes and call the class when required.

As I say, this isn't the perfect answer to my original problem but it was a work around I discovered and as a result it may help others if they read this SO post.

Answer (score 0):

I have already heard/read some problem that people are facing when they are using timer in windows service. Instead of using timer I'd recommend in OnStart method start a task that uses loop with integrated delay. something like following:

```
Task _task;
CancellationTokenSource _terminator;

protected override void OnStart()
{
     _terminator = new CancellationTokenSource();
     _task = Task.Factory.StartNew(TaskBody, _terminator.Token);
}

private void TaskBody(object arg)
{
     var ct = arg as CancellationToken;

     if (ct == null) throw new ArgumentException();

     while(!ct.sCancellationRequested)
     {
         YourOnTimerMethod();
         ct.WaitHandle.WaitOne(interval)
     }
}

public override void OnClose()
{
    _terminator.Cancel();
    _task.Wait();
}
```

Comment: Just tried this fix and it still isn't running the second service. Don't know what to try next...

Comment: suggestion... Be sure that onStart of your 2 services are implemented in the way i propose above. Comment you current implementation of YourOnTimerMethod() and enable something rather simple (for example write a value in log ). check your logs if both services writing their values.

Comment: Do you think service1 should also have this implementation?

Comment: Definetly. Both services should have a thread start in their OnStart methods

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Seems that the OnStart method is called only on the first Service passed to ServiceBase.Run.

Comment: No.  It is called only on the service that received a start request.  That might be the first one in the list, but it doesn't have to be.  The order in which the services are passed to `Servicebase.Run` is irrelevant.